# First usable addresses

Tags: cisco, ip-address

Network id: 173.128.0.0/18
We have two different networks
Network A has 3319 usable hosts and Network B 126
I calculated their subnet masks, but now I am not sure how to calculate their first and last usable addresses
Is it 173.128.0.1 or 173.128.15.1

Comment: 3319 usable host addresses isn't possible with IP. It's always 2^n-2 for IPv4.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) has a section about this: **Subnet Size Based on Number of Hosts**